# Given 3 columns (sid, date, tid) and primary key (date, tid). Find the sids that have every tid

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Given this relation call it

winners

```
sid date tid
1   2011 1
2   2012 1
1   2011 2
2   2012 2
3   2013 1
```

This is the table properties

```
CREATE TABLE winners(
    sid     INTEGER     REFERENCES student(sid),
    date    INTEGER     NOT NULL, 
    tid     INTEGER     REFERENCES tournament(tid),
    PRIMARY KEY(tid, date));
```

I want to query such that I find the sids that won every tournament.

In this case I want the output to be

```
sid
1
2
```

Because there is only 2 tournaments (tid 1 and 2) and sid 1 and 2 won both of them.

MY ATTEMPT

this query will return

```
CREATE VIEW uniquetids AS
SELECT DISTINCT count(tid), sid FROM winners GROUP BY sid;
-----------

count  sid
2      1
2      2
1      3
```

Now what? Not sure how to get 1 2 only

Comment: *In this case I want the output to be* Absolutely unclear... there exists a tournament 1 in 2013 which was NOT won by sid 1/2...

Comment: The tournament won in 2013 is tid 1 which was won by sid 1/2. tid isnt unique, (tid, date) is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should serve your purpose.

```sql
WITH cdata AS (
    SELECT 
        sid, 
        count(DISTINCT tid) tid_count 
    FROM winners 
    GROUP BY sid
)
SELECT 
    sid 
FROM cdata 
WHERE 
    tid_count = (SELECT max(tid_count) FROM cdata)
```

Comment: I think that should be `count(DISTINCT tid)`.

Comment: I think you should use the same in the final subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little hack-ish, and would fail if you could have a student win a tournament twice. And there may be other scenarios... But with what you have:

```
SELECT sid 
FROM (
    SELECT sid, count(1) won 
    FROM winners 
    GROUP BY sid
) win_counts
WHERE won = (SELECT count(tid) FROM TOURNAMENT)
```

Comment: I think that should be `count(DISTINCT tid)` in buth cases.